# Browser Issue with Ripple Button Effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser

```js
//Adapted from http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/ripple-click-effect-google-material-design
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ink, d, x, y;
    $(".ripple-dark").mousedown(function (e) {
        if ($(this).find(".circle-dark").length === 0) {
            $(this).prepend("<span class='circle-dark'></span>");
        }

        ink = $(this).find(".circle-dark");
        ink.removeClass("animate-dark");

        if (!ink.height() && !ink.width()) {
            d = Math.max($(this).outerWidth(), $(this).outerHeight());
            ink.css({
                height: d,
                width: d
            });
        }

        x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - ink.width() / 2;
        y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - ink.height() / 2;

        ink.css({
            top: y + 'px',
            left: x + 'px'
        }).addClass("animate-dark");
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    var ink, d, x, y;
    $(".ripple-light").mousedown(function (e) {
        if ($(this).find(".circle-light").length === 0) {
            $(this).prepend("<span class='circle-light'></span>");
        }

        ink = $(this).find(".circle-light");
        ink.removeClass("animate-light");

        if (!ink.height() && !ink.width()) {
            d = Math.max($(this).outerWidth(), $(this).outerHeight());
            ink.css({
                height: d,
                width: d
            });
        }

        x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - ink.width() / 2;
        y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - ink.height() / 2;

        ink.css({
            top: y + 'px',
            left: x + 'px'
        }).addClass("animate-light");
    });
});
```

```css
.button {
  background: gray;
  padding: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ripple-dark,
.ripple-light {
    display: inline-block;
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.circle-dark {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: scale(0);
}

.animate-dark {
    animation: ripple 0.45s linear;
}

@keyframes ripple {
    80% {
        opacity: 0.9;
        transform: scale(3);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(4);
    }
}

.circle-light {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: scale(0);
}

.animate-light {
    animation: ripple 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="button ripple-light" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Hi</a>
```

While playing around with some codes for a while, I found a cool plugin that adds a "ripple" effect to whatever element you want [at this link](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/ripple-click-effect-google-material-design). I decided to play around with the code a little, creating both a light and a dark "ripple" theme for buttons. However, I have noticed a few issues with my code.

For hyperlinks, my changes to the effect work perfectly in Chrome, but require a double-click in Desktop Safari and Firefox. I don't have a Windows machine handy, so I'm not sure if Edge or Internet Explorer have this issue too. I figured that this must have something to do with the dark and light themes I created, since the original code seems to work fine with a hyperlink. You can see an example of my changes in effect [at this link](https://jsfiddle.net/L0oxy932/).

Could somebody help me figure out the reason why my changes to the effect require a double click in some browsers, and a way to prevent this from happening? I'd like to have it so it's a single-click, not a double-click.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hate to say it but, works on my machine - FF 54.0.1.

Comment: Ripple doesn't work in Edge but the link does. (The ripple works in FF but the link doesn't.) (Win10.)

Comment: @wazz Thanks for letting me know! I'm running MacOS 10.13. Any suggestions for how to fix this?? My Firefox version is 56.0.2

Comment: I've tried a couple things but no luck. Prefixes don't seem to do anything.